# How to check if a userform is closed with "X" Windows button?

Tags: vba

There is a sub, it creates a `CourtForm` userform and then takes a data from it. The problem appears when said form is closed prematurely, by pressing "X" window button and I get a runtime error somewhere later. For reference, this is what I'm talking about:

[image]
In my code I tried to make a check to exit sub:

```
Private Sub test()

    'Create an exemplar of a form
    Dim CourtForm As New FormSelectCourt
    CourtForm.Show

    'The form is terminated at this point

    'Checking if the form is terminated. The check always fails. Form exists but without any data.
    If CourtForm Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This code executes when the form proceeds as usual, recieves 
    '.CourtName and .CourtType variable data and then .hide itself.

    CourtName = CourtForm.CourtName
    CourtType = CourtForm.CourtType
    Unload CourtForm


    'Rest of the code, with the form closed a runtime error occurs here

End Sub
```

Apparently the exemplar of the form exists, but without any data. Here's a screenshot of the watch:

[image]

How do I make a proper check for the form if it's closed prematurely?

Comment: Are there any other ways to close the window excepting by pressing "X" window button? What will be a normal flow when the window isn't closed prematurely? How does the sub takes a data from the userform?

Comment: Updated my code. Basically the form writes data to several local variables such as `CaseForm.CourtName`, `CaseForm.CourtType` and then executes `me.hide`, allowing the sub to take data from those variables and then unload the userform. If user decides to close userform before picking up the values the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code to your userform

```
    Private m_Cancelled As Boolean

    ' Returns the cancelled value to the calling procedure
    Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
        Cancelled = m_Cancelled
    End Property

    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                           , CloseMode As Integer)

        ' Prevent the form being unloaded
        If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True

        ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
        Hide
        m_Cancelled = True

    End Sub
```

Code taken from [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/#Cancelling_the_UserForm). I would really recommend to have a read there as you will find a pretty good basic explanation how to use a userform.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is to pass a dictionary to the user form, and store all entered data into it. Here is the example:

User form module code:

```vb
' Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' Assumed the userform with 2 listbox and button

Option Explicit

Public data As New Dictionary

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ListBox1.List = Array("item1", "item2", "item3")
    Me.ListBox2.List = Array("item1", "item2", "item3")

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    data("quit") = False
    data("courtName") = Me.ListBox1.Value
    data("courtType") = Me.ListBox2.Value
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Standard module code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim data As New Dictionary

    data("quit") = True
    Load UserForm1
    Set UserForm1.data = data
    UserForm1.Show

    If data("quit") Then
        MsgBox "Ввод данных отменен пользователем"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox data("courtName")
    MsgBox data("courtType")

End Sub
```

Note the user form in that case can be closed (i. e. unloaded) right after all data is filled in and action button is clicked by user.

Another way is to check if the user form actually loaded:

```vb
Sub test()

    UserForm1.Show

    If Not isUserFormLoaded("UserForm1") Then
        MsgBox "Ввод данных отменен пользователем"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Function isUserFormLoaded(userFormName As String) As Boolean

    Dim uf As Object

    For Each uf In UserForms
        If LCase(uf.Name) = LCase(userFormName) Then
            isUserFormLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely the most simple way:

1. In the component any procedure shows the UserForm declare:

```
Public Terminated As Boolean
```

2. In the UserForm write:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    <component>.Terminated = True
End Sub
```

3. In the calling procedure write:

```
    <userform>.Show
    If Terminated Then ....
```